# $ajax() call works in Firefox not Webkit/Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

The following $ajax() call works fine from firefox but returns "error" status text and '0' status in webkit.  The url is a cakePHP specific controller action that returns html.  The Id passed to the ajax call comes from an option select and is functioning properly in both browsers.

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : "http://mysite.com/controller/controllername/action/",
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {'itemId':Id},
  success: ajaxSuccess,
  error: ajaxError,
  complete: ajaxComplete
});
function ajaxComplete(jqXHR, textStatus){
  console.log("complete: " + textStatus);
  console.log("complete: " + jqXHR);
}
function ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
  console.log(errorThrown);
  console.log(textStatus);
  console.log(jqXHR);
}
function ajaxSuccess(result, status, jqXHR){        
 console.log(result);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this would work in firefox and not in Webkit/Chrome?  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Chrome: F12 -> Network tab, check the status, headers and response there.

Comment: I wonder how the code shown is called.

Comment: It is quite possible you're running into cross-site restrictions. As @FabrícioMatté said, check the Network tab for more details.

Comment: update url like url : "/controller/controllername/action/",